# Is a centralized processing of request header data possible?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing, request-headers

Let me explain what my problem is:

In a Web API project I am facing the issue that every single request which is sent to my controller has to contain some header data which should be processed before the controller action runs.

So as far as I know, I could include a new argument on every single action and decorate it with a `FromHeader` Attribute. Currently there are about 2000 actions from several controllers where I would have to change the parameter signature. So it would be a much prettier solution, if I could centralize the processing of this header data.

I am looking for some code to overwrite which is between the constructor of the controller class and the execution of the controller's action. Does anybody know a method for overriding or a pattern to accomplish this requirement? May be there is a possibility to extend the routing to the action

Comment: like https://medium.com/@lucaslra/asp-net-core-mvc-pipeline-routing-middleware-custom-irouter-d101202e0a14 ?

Comment: Is `OnActionExecuting` the answer? I've just recognized that my controllers had `ControllerBase` as base class. After changing it to `Controller` as super class it, I've noticed this method. Could this be the solution?

Comment: I thought you said you wanted to alter the routing.. Surely by the time an action is executing the routing has been done?

Comment: Seems to work to include my stuff in `OnActionExecuting`.
I was not sure, if I have to modify some part of the routing or not. But currently I am quite happy with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    /*
    PUT YOUR CODE HERE ;-)
    */
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```